# DetailsView Update command doesn't update unless all of the fields are present!

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, detailsview

I have a page that binds data from DB to a DetailsView.

I want to use the auto-generated Update command.

Everything went OK, and also updating was successful, but if I remove any field that I don't want to have chance to update, then the Update command doesn't update! the old values retain!

I mean: if all of the fields are present in the detailsView, the update will be OK, otherwise, the update will NOT update any thing.

I've tried to mark the fields that I don't want to view as "Visible = 'false'" but with no good results!

How could I hide some fields?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the field you don't want to update at 'ReadOnly = True' too? This should mark them as to not be updated.

Comment: Thanks, that should make the field to be appear, but not updatable, but I'm aiming to NOT view it at all!

Comment: Didi you try to make it 'Visible = False' AND 'ReadOnly = True'?

Comment: Yes I tried, but that considered as it's not included at all, no updating occured :(

Comment: I am somewhat out of ideas and can't really test anything right now. Maybe the problem is with the datasource too...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it..

```
protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        foreach (DataControlField fd in DetailsView1.Fields)
        {
            BoundField tmp = fd as BoundField;
            if (tmp != null)
                if (tmp.DataField == "YourReadOnlyColumnName")
                    tmp.ReadOnly = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should make the field to be appear, but not updatable, but I'm aiming to NOT view it at all!